# ClipDrawable width does not fit its parent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have the parent relative layout with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and a child ClipDrawable width also set to `android:layout_width="match_parent` ,but the ClipDrawable does not fit the parent width though the parent layout does not have a padding at all. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: can you please add your code, as well the screen shot of the output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` will make the ClipDrawable image fit it's parent.